# Microsoft Teams Bot using Bot Framework SDK (Java) - Conversations not loading after I navigate directly from my Apps' static tabs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Building a MS Teams Bot using Bot Framework SDK (Java).My App has a Chat tab (actual Bot) + few static tabs. Issue I'm facing on both Desktop and Web versions of Teams is when I do the below navigation:

1. Apps' Chat tab (working) -> Any of the static tabs(working) -> Any existing conversations (Not working - None of the conversations loads)
2. Apps' Chat tab (working) -> Any of the static tabs(working) -> again back to Apps' Chat tab -> Any existing conversations (All working)

Only way I can fix this issue is Logout/Restart the Teams App. Any guidance/help is much appreciated. Please let me know if more info is required or if I'm not clear. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqDjJ.png 
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S92C.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps or screenshots, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Attached a diagram.Let me know if that helps.Thanks!

Comment: @SunDev-We are unable to repro the scenario. Could you please update the version of teams and check it once?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Looks like the Teams app is up-to-date. "You have Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.4683. It was last updated on 2/25/22". Also, attached a screenshot of an error on the browser's console when I checked used Teams Web version.

Comment: Attached a Video. It is working for us.
https://youtu.be/P6xeT24Frdc

Comment: Moved away from "ContentBotId" to "ContentURL" for the static tabs (Teams App  manifest) and serving the content. It looks good now.

Comment: If your issue is resolved. Could please add it as answer for more visibility? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you